# Create a variable from another variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, tail

In a `shell` script I will store the output as a variable like below

```
Test=$(/home/$USER/import.py $table)
```

Now this `Test` variable will have more than 2 lines like below

```
table= 123_test
min_id=1
max_id=100
123_test,1,100
```

Now I want to store the last line of the `Test` variable as another variable called `output`.

I have tried like below. But not getting the desired result

```
output=`$test | tail -n 1`
```

Can we create a variable from another variable in a `shell` script. If yes, How can we do that?

Comment: simply: `output=${Test##*$'\n'}` or you might wrote: `output=\`echo "$Test" | tail -n1\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `echo` to pipe the variable to the other command.

```
output=$(echo "$test" | tail -1)
```

or a here-string:

```
output=$(tail -1 <<<"$test")
```

Don't forget to quote the variable in both cases, otherwise all the lines will be combined.

Finally, you can use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operator to select the last line, instead of using `tail`:

```
output=${test##*$'\n'}
```

Comment: or `echo ${test##*$'\n'}`